# Sumar un año ingresado en la columna 1 y mostrarlo en la columna 2 en un array de filas dinámicas

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buen día, estoy aprendiendo Javascript y me encontré con esta dificultad, necesito que al ingresar una fecha en la primera columna se agregue en la segunda columna la fecha con un año mas, actualmente sólo funciona la primera fila, a partir de la segunda ya no funciona, agradezco su atención, saludos cordiales.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function addYear() {
    var days = 365;
    var date = new Date(document.getElementById("factory_date").value);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(days));
    document.getElementById("end_date").valueAsDate = date;
  }
</script>
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="factory_date[]" id="factory_date" value="" required onchange="addYear();"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="end_date[]" id="end_date" value="" required></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="factory_date[]" id="factory_date" value="" required onchange="addYear();"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="end_date[]" id="end_date" value="" required></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="factory_date[]" id="factory_date" value="" required onchange="addYear();"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="end_date[]" id="end_date" value="" required></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba realizando estos cambios:

1. Donde pones:

```
onchange="addYear();"
```

cambialo por:

```
onchange="addYear(this);"
```

2. Reescribe la función de este modo:

```
function addYear(item) {
  var days = 365;
  var date = new Date(item.value);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(days));
  item.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstChild.valueAsDate = date
}
```

pues lo que hacemos es detectar el elemento seleccionado (**item**) y partiendo de el nos movemos por el DOM actual que tienes, donde:

```
  item                   --> representa el objeto actual, es decir, el input
    .parentElement       --> sube un nivel, situándose en la columna <td>
    .nextElementSibling  --> se mueve a la siguente columna <td>
    .firstChild          --> desciende al primer hijo que encuentra, el input del vencimiento
    .valueAsDate = date  --> le asigna el valor deseado
```

Y en este snippet de ejemplo todo junto:

```js
function addYear(item) {
  var days = 365;
  var date = new Date(item.value);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(days));
  item.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstChild.valueAsDate = date
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="factory_date[]" id="factory_date" value="" required onchange="addYear(this);"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="end_date[]" id="end_date" value="" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="factory_date[]" id="factory_date" value="" required onchange="addYear(this);"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="end_date[]" id="end_date" value="" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="factory_date[]" id="factory_date" value="" required onchange="addYear(this);"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="end_date[]" id="end_date" value="" required></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente y con la explicación del código me ayudas mucho, estoy aprendiendo javascript y a veces tengo inconvenientes, gracias @masterguru